# Moving Smarty website to new server

Tags: migration, smarty, installation

I'm moving a website to a new domain and server and I'm running into some problems. This website works with Smarty, and I've never used it before. I think I got a very basic problem, but I can't find the answer online.

- I've moved all the FTP files to the new server
- I've copied the database
- I've edited the config file with the new database information

Now only EVERY page (even a blank `test.php` file with a simple `echo`) I get "failed to open stream" errors.

```
Warning: rename(/home/*websitename*/domains/*websitename*.com/public_html//skins/default/compiled/65e3d4d7349f9687ce73f56b61992749304409a2.file.index.tpl.php) [function.rename]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/*websitename*/domains/*websitename*.com/public_html/external/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 48

Warning: rename(/tmp/wrtPBIHNP,/home/*websitename*/domains/*websitename*.com/public_html//skins/default/compiled/65e3d4d7349f9687ce73f56b61992749304409a2.file.index.tpl.php) [function.rename]: Permission denied in /home/*websitename*/domains/*websitename*.com/public_html/external/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 48

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in /home/*websitename*/domains/*websitename*.com/public_html/external/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 50

Warning: include(/home/*websitename*/domains/*websitename*.com/public_html//skins/default/compiled/65e3d4d7349f9687ce73f56b61992749304409a2.file.index.tpl.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/*websitename*/domains/*websitename*.com/public_html/external/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php on line 432

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/*websitename*/domains/*websitename*.com/public_html//skins/default/compiled/65e3d4d7349f9687ce73f56b61992749304409a2.file.index.tpl.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/*websitename*/domains/*websitename*.com/public_html/external/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php on line 432
```

- It looks like a problem with premissions, but I've made EVERY file on the FTP premission 777 (to test) and this does not solve it.
- There are two backslashes `/public_html//skins/` which is weird.
- The code is exactly the same on the "old" server, besides the config file. Only thing new is the domain name.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set for directory compiled permissions 755 or 777.

You should probably also remove all compiled and cached files (if you use cache) because it may also cause problems